# remove inbox folder after open in files from other app to my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsfilemanager

I have used this code for open other files imported from other app via openin menu
but the problem is that when i try to delete in box folder after importing document it gives me permission error

```
   -(void)openImportedFile:(NSURL *)url{

    NSFileManager *filemanager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *strfilepath=[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *inboxPath=[strfilepath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NewDocument"];
    [filemanager createDirectoryAtPath:inboxPath withIntermediateDirectories:TRUE attributes:nil error:nil];
    NSString *strInboxFilepath=[url path];
    NSString *strdesPath=[inboxPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[strInboxFilepath lastPathComponent]];
    [self performSelector:@selector(deleteInboxFolder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];

    self.docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:strdesPath]];
    self.docController.delegate = self;
    [self.docController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];

    }
```

This is code for delete inbox folder

```
 -(void)deleteInboxFolder
    {
        NSFileManager *fm=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSError *error;
 NSString *strfilepath=[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Inbox",strfilepath];
        [fm removeItemAtPath:path error:&error];
        if(error){
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
        }

    }
```

I am getting this belowed error

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 513.)" UserInfo=0x16d5e7f0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x16d5e6d0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted", NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Applications/D1252FCA-A496-45EE-80FC-4F6692AF4545/Documents/Inbox, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Remove
)}
```

I am totally confused what to do
please suggest me solution
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you find a way to delete the inbox folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this directory can not be deleted as it was created from the system and you have no rights to do so.
Though not very clearly stated but the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) give you at least a hint.